# How can I add motion blur to an animated image in the video editor?

Tags: image, video, blur

How can I add motion blur to an animated image track in the video editor. For instance, If I key framed an image track to swipe in fast from the side, how can I give the image motion blur while it's moving, but not when it's still? 
(Without using the compositor) If anyone could answer this I would be I would be eternally grateful. :)

(Sorry about the lack of images, If you need some for reference please tell me.)

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what you're after, but basically there are different types of blur. 1. Compositor blur - there are sub-types within this category, but essentially you're blurring flat images 2. Motion blur (relies on movement and is calculated in the render) 3. Depth of Field A.K.A. DOF blur (is a camera setting and is also calculated in the render). It sounds like you want to use motion blur, but between what and what? Motion blur obviously does not apply if the subject(s) are not in motion.

Comment: What I want to blur an image overlay that moves from place to place. But if I use Gaussian blur it's always blured.